# How to use the JS ctx.translate function to lock player in center of screen?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have the following JS function to render a "player" in the center of the viewport.

```js
//state fires every 60ms 
socket.on('state', (gameState) => {
//iterates through gameState players
    for (let player in gameState.players) {
//draws each player
        renderEnemies(gameState.players[player]);
    }
});

function renderEnemies(player) {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('gameboard').getContext('2d');
    const canvas = document.getElementById('gameboard');
//align player with center of viewport (BROKEN)
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2- player.x, canvas.height/2-player.y);
//colour player red
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
//add the player to the canvas (gameboard)
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.width); 
}
```

However, the translate part of the renderEnemies function doesn't work. I have already experimented with ctx.clear() and restore, but to no avail.

I would appreciate it if someone would point me in the right direction.
Thanks!

UPDATE: I have fixed the viewport error with the below code, but the player movement is now broken. The draw function now looks like this:

```js
function renderEnemies(player) {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('gameboard').getContext('2d');
    const canvas = document.getElementById('gameboard');

    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.translate(window.innerWidth/2- player.x, window.innerHeight/2-player.y);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.width); 
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to the fact that you are not saving and restoring or at least translating back after you draw. As you can see in the snippet below if I translate without doing either the enemy gets translated incorrectly (off canvas in this example).

When you un-comment save AND restore it correctly positions. You can also just translate it back by adding negative values after you draw. So in the snippte below you can comment out the `save()` and `reastore()` and uncomment the second `translate` and you get the same results.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
class Enemy {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = 20;
    this.h = 20;
    this.c = "blue";
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2 - this.w/2, canvas.height / 2 - this.h/2);
    //colour player red
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    //add the player to the canvas (gameboard)
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    ctx.restore();
    //ctx.translate(-(canvas.width / 2 - this.w/2), -(canvas.height / 2 - this.h/2)); //or use this
  }
}
let enemy1 = new Enemy(0, 0);

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  enemy1.draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Without all of your code I don't know what else it may be.

UPDATE:

Knowing the fundamentals of what `translate()` is doing will help you understand what is happening when you translate something. Don't just think of translate as the canvas is moving that object but think of it as that object is on a canvas sheet of it own and that entire sheet is being moved. This is why if you rotate an item it does not rotate from the center but rather the (0,0) position of the canvas. Think of it this way , when you input values into translate you are telling it where you want the top-left corner of that sheet of canvas for that specific item to be.

[image]

In the image above the solid black is the canvas. If I translate the red square to `ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2)` then you can see I am actually translating the sheet of canvas depicted by the grey border. The top-left of that canvas is centered on the canvas but because the square is draw at (0,0) it will appear that the square is not centered bu slightly to the right and down. Also if I were to give the red square object an x-coordinate of (canvas.width/2, 0) then you can see what will happen depicted by the red border square.

Now in the next image if I really wanted to center the red square I would need to account for half of the width and height. I can do this in two places. If I subtract it in the translate method `ctx.translate(canvas.width/2 - block.width/2, canvas.height/2 - block.height/2)` it will center but this also keeps the squares (0,0) in line with the canvas (0,0). That is okay until you may want to rotate the red square from the center.

[image]

In the picture above I set the subtraction on the red squares coordinates instead `(0 - this.width/2, 0 - this.height/2)` this puts the (0,0) of the canvas in the center of the red square. Since roatation happens from the (0,0) of the canvas that red square if rotated will spin from the center.

With all that said If you are applying x and y coordinates to your object and trying to translate the same amount you will have errors like the first image red outline. In other words don't do this (unless you mean to)

`ctx.translate(100, 100)`
`ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 50, 50)`

that will translate it 100 each way and then the object will have an additional 100 in each direction. Also you probabky don't need to use clearRect inside you save(). That is normally called on update at the begining of the animation loop to clear the canvas before redrawing.

Comment: Thanks! I sort of fixed it by using window.innerWidth and Height, but now have issues with the movement. I know it is a lot to ask, but would you look at my edit to the question, with the updated code, and attempt to figure-out why the movement doesn't work? I'd assume it's something to do with my ctx.save() and ctx.restore()

Comment: I updated my comment to try to bring some clarity to `translate`. Also if it broke your movement I am wonder if you have collision detection on the canvas set up and maybe since the translations are wrong it is colliding at all times.